# Is there a queue for SQL jobs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm atm working to create a huge mySQL database by parsing XML files released on a FTP.

On a single computer, it takes ages, because of the huge amount of SQL INSERT INTO to make.

Thus, I modified my code to build it on AWS by creating a cluster, launching a database, build everything and download back the dump.

However, I got a question. Is there a "queue" for SQL requests sent ? I mean, if every of my nodes are sending requests at the same time to the database, what's going to happen ?

Thanks

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different, unrelated software packages produced by different companies. Please use only the correct tag. Also, it seems your question refers to a certain implementation, it is not a question about the SQL language.

Comment: So, is there a tag for it ?

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL you can use [`SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-processlist.html) to see the open connections and what query they are running at the moment.

There is no queue of requests but some requests waits for others to complete, before starting, because they attempt to use rows or tables that are locked by the requests that are currently running.

Only one request is executed at a time for each connection.

Comment: You mean one table is locked during INSERT ? And every of my nodes will have a different connexion to the DB, the the database itself won't be lock when one of my node is inserting ?

Comment: Depending on the [engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-engines.html) used to store the table, some operations lock the entire table and others lock only the rows it uses. There are many types of [locking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html) and some of them (shared locks) allow other requests to read the locked rows (but delay the writing) while others (exclusive locks) do not allow other rows handle the locked rows (either for reading or writing). The statements that modify the table data use exclusive locks.